# Split strings without splitter

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, coordinates, latitude-longitude

usually, I use **14.some numbers** and **121.some numbers** as map coordinates on my app.
While I am working on a new module that sends different gps logs, I get this coordinates:

`1434.7906`
`12103.5434`

at first I thought my app is not routing, but then I saw that the coordinates given is off, or bluntly, in wrong format (*decimal places moved to the right twice*). Is there something wrong with the module? Or is there a formula to convert it to normal coordinates?

**EDIT UPDATE:** I discovered that the above format is on 14D 34M 7906S--*(got this from the link below)*
Which eventually, gave me a problem. *changed the title*
How can I convert it to *Decimal Form*?

- Answer : something like split it after to chars. --> My first thought, but..

How about 12103? I need it to be 121 and 03 - which needed to split after 3 chars. Thus I can't control the burst of string to even to that. Need help! thanks

At the end of the day, I need those 2 above to be converted to this: 
`14.5798433°, 121.0590567°`
[***Calc Source***](http://www.earthpoint.us/convert.aspx)

[image]

Comment: _... I discovered that the above format is on 14D 34M 7906S..._ I get the feeling that your assumptions about the fromat are not entirely correct... Why would you have 2D 11M 46S expressed as 7906S?

Comment: Your input seems a bit confusing, but you might be able to do things mathematically by verifying which parts can be degree, minutes and seconds based on the rules based on the mathematical limits/values they can take.

Comment: the exact data I am getting is the two on top.. Now as I've researched a bit, if they will be expanded 1434.7906 is equivalent to 14Degrees, 34Minutes 7906Seconds. (14°34.79060', 121°03.54340')

Comment: `7906Seconds` makes no sense, they look like decimal fractions of minutes.

Comment: yeah me too, just like @AlexFilipovici said, its 2D 11M 46S. though from the link I have stated above, it gave me that answer and the decimal form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing you have leading zeroes (matters for other parts of the world), longtitudes are always 3 digits (0-180) and latitudes are 2 digits (0-90).

The notation only makes sense if it is about degrees + decimal minutes, ie

```
1434.7906  = 14° + 34.79060' = 14 + (34.79060 / 60) °
```

In C#, untested:

```
string lat = ..., lon = ...;

double la = double.Parse(lat.Substring(0, 2)) + double.Parse(lat.Substring(2)) / 60.0;
double lo = double.Parse(lon.Substring(0, 3)) + double.Parse(lon.Substring(3)) / 60.0;
```

Comment: Thanks! Alot.. you have deep comprehension skills sir :>

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with coordinates but it looks like the first of your value before the period have to be 5 digits and the second value 4 digits. So I would split first on the period (full stop) character. Then if the first value is 4 digits pad to 5 by placing a 0 in front. Then split on position so you have 014 and 34 which would then become 14 and 34. et al.

Answer (score 0):

by shell to split the number

```
$     echo 1434 |sed 's/\(..\)$/ \1/'
14 34

$     echo 12103 |sed 's/\(..\)$/ \1/'
121 03
```

If you need handle the whole number with expect output:

```
$     echo 1434.7906 |sed -r 's/(.*)(..)\.(.*)/\1Degress, \2Minutes \3Seconds/'
14Degress, 34Minutes 7906Seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that longitude and latitude can be negative. Here is a function that is messy in type conversion:

```
    Function DecDegree(dd_mm_decmm As String) As String
      Dim deg As String = dd_mm_decmm.Substring(0, dd_mm_decmm.IndexOf(".") - 2)
      Dim mm_dec As String = dd_mm_decmm.Substring(dd_mm_decmm.IndexOf(".") - 2)
      Dim decDegrees As Double = CDbl(deg) + (CDbl(mm_dec / 60) * If(CDbl(deg) < 0, -1, 1))
      Return FormatNumber(decDegrees, 6)
    End Function
```

The split is based on the location of the decimal point. The math for the minutes conversion checks to see if it needs to add or subtract. The func returns 6 decimal points which is plenty for any but survey grade GPS.

Comment: sorry, but how can I use this? say, I want to convert those two given above.

Comment: I would leave out that last FormatNumber() and just return decDegrees.

Comment: convert two: call the func twice

Comment: six digits of lat/long is more accurate then most devices that gather lat/long and more accurate than most GPS can expect. Fine with me however :)